# How many pages have I torn out?

Tags: code-golf

Last month I borrowed a plenty of books from the library. They all were good books, packed with emotions and plot-twists. Unfortunately, at some points I got very angry/sad/disappointed, so I tore some pages out.

Now the library wants to know how many pages I have torn out for each book.

Your goal is to write a program, which takes a sorted, comma-delimited list of numbers as input and prints the minimum and maximum possible page count I could have torn out. Each line represents a book, each number represents a missing page from the book.

Example input:

```
7,8,100,101,222,223
2,3,88,89,90,103,177
2,3,6,7,10,11
1
1,2
```

Example output:

```
4/5
5/6
3/6
1/1
1/2
```

`4/5` means, that I may have torn out either 4 or 5 pages, depending on which side the book's page numbering starts. One could have torn out page 6/7, page 8/9, page 100/101, and page 222/223 (4 pages). Alternatively, one could have torn out page 7/8, page 99/100, page 101/102, page 221/222, and page 223/224 (5 pages).

Remember that a book page always has a front and a back side. Also the page numbering differs from book to book. Some books have even page numbers on the left page; some on the right page. All books are read from left to right.

Shortest code in bytes win. Strict I/O format is **not** required. Your programs must be able to take one or more books as input. Have fun.

Comment: Would it be acceptable if the output values are not guaranteed to be sorted? (such as `4/5` and `5/4`)

Comment: Don't forget to update to the challenges to specify that output order must be consistent, either all `min/max` or all `max/min`. (Although, personally, I'd prefer that not to be part of the spec!)

Comment: What would be the reason to `programs must be able to take one or more books as input` rule? Most (if not all) will just wrap the code to verify a single book into a loop or something. IMHO it just add an overhead to the answer with little to no gains to the challenge. This questions already got lots of answers, so it's better to keep this as is, but keep this in mind for you future challenges.

Comment: Suggested test case (courtesy of @Arnauld): `1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,18` - for the benefit of languages whose built-in `sort` method sorts lexicographically by default (assuming the requirement of consistently sorted output *is* added to the spec).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
εD>)ÅÈε€θγg}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3FYXO83DrYc7zm191LTm3I5zm9Nrq///j44217HQMTQwAGJDHSMjIyA2jtWJNtIx1rGw0LGw1LEESRnrGJqbQ4XNdMyBIjqGhkA@UEtsLAA)

Thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) for the heads-up on spec changes.

#### Explanation

```
εD>)ÅÈε€θγg}{ – Full program.
ε             – For each book...
 D            – Push two copies of it.
  >           – Increment all the elements of the second copy.
   )          – Wrap the whole stack into a list.
    ÅÈ        – Produces the lists of even natural numbers lower or equal to each element.
      ε       – For each (the modified copies of the book):
       €θ     – Get the last item of each.
         γg   – And split into chunks of equal adjacent elements.
           }  – Close the loop.
            { – Sort the resulting list.
```

Comment: Nice submission. I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required.

Comment: Btw, your program does not take multiple books as input.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks for the heads-up. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @arminb It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> <s>56</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```python
lambda b:[map(len,map(set,zip(*[[p/2,-p/2]for p in t])))for t in b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU1LDoMgEN17CnZK80wFk4Im7UUoC001NVEkyqa9PB1IF2/ebybjP@G9Oxnn@zOuwza@Bjb2Zht8tU4Oic8p4Lv46mKMv0rUNOy8H8yzxbFgOefJheRGG7OezmxNYYyChmgagoCUktBaC0aNRAutoTt0qW4hlLLI8Q2KEgjxXxVEhu7JFrYvmD8WF/IblPWjxFwlzeMP)

Comment: Your program does not accept multiple line inputs (multiple books). I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required.

Comment: Wouldn't multiple inputs per run fall into strict I/O?

Comment: One could argue.

Comment: *How* you take the books and their pages as input is covered by the I/O spec. The requirement that you *do* take multiple books as input is part of the challenge spec.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>104</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> <s>85</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 74 bytes

Would be [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZCxasMwEIb3PIUJHSR8EZZManuQtg7t0AwZHYGUWA4OqWxsp41b99ndS1IoLfRAB/r@D06ng3213a6tmn7h68JNpZysVJa92Iacpcoj4Pp68VJ59xasXU/OVzBINYReKU4p66p3R@m0q31XHx071ntigkffnPrgvxqD1alHYePvPszCsNY1zvYk5vRz/EUEko03YT7L8wRS4BG@KeIghMATaw0YCIghTSHNILukMfAk@UnuIUEInN8QR7RElCEBju4SdeDpd6oBDYH9Mkvr2W3/rVQmMOHTevXMur6t/L4qB7KlrLHFgy9IHNFwPgbzv0aJDv7Qoa68wTXo9AU) if not for the unnecessary (in my opinion) requirement that each pair of numbers in the output be consistently sorted, or [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZCxboMwEIZ3nsKKOtjiYmGjFBjw1qEdmiEjQbITTESUGgROK1r67PRI1aGVasmW7vs/6e58Nq9mOPZN59eurexc57PJVRGBKPmL6ajLlbNvZGc9NTcw5moMnVKCMT4075bNx9YN7cXyS3uimjy67urJf2ci26tHYe/uPvRa89521ngaC/Y5/SISyd7psAiKBFIQEU4UCZBS4o1LCAoJMaQppBlkSxaDSJIffg8JIhBiAQLBBkGGNQj0NqiCSG9ZCZhLfJceZfC99CFXmujwabd95oPvG3dq6pEeGO9M9eAqGkcsXE1k9deo0cFvObeN0zg8m78A) if we only needed to take one book as input.

Input and output are both an array of arrays.

```js
a=>a.map(x=>[0,1].map(n=>new Set(x.map(y=>y+n>>1)).size).sort((x,y)=>x-y))
```

- Initially inspired by [Olivier's Java solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154997/58974) and my own (currently deleted) Japt solution.
- 2 bytes saved thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) (plus another 3 we both spotted at the same time) and 10 bytes *added* thanks to him spotting the broken sorting I'd hoped nobody would notice while that requirement was still under discussion!

---

### Test cases

Test cases are split into individual books for better readability with the last case (which includes the `[1,2]` edge case) serving to illustrate that this solution supports multiple books in the input.

```js
f=
a=>a.map(x=>[0,1].map(n=>new Set(x.map(y=>y+n>>1)).size).sort((x,y)=>x-y))
o.innerText=` Input                         | Output\n${`-`.repeat(31)}|${`-`.repeat(21)}\n`+[[[7,8,100,101,222,223]],[[2,3,88,89,90,103,177]],[[2,3,6,7,10,11]],[[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,18]],[[1],[1,2],[8,10]]].map(b=>` `+JSON.stringify(b).padEnd(30)+"| "+JSON.stringify(f(b))).join`\n`
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

---

### History

```js
//104
a=>a.map(x=>x.map(y=>b.add(y/2|0)&c.add(++y/2|0),b=new Set,c=new Set)&&[b.size,c.size].sort((x,y)=>x-y)))
// 93
a=>a.map(x=>[new Set(x.map(y=>y/2|0)).size,new Set(x.map(y=>++y/2|0)).size].sort((x,y)=>x-y)))
// 92
a=>a.map(x=>[(g=z=>new Set(z).size)(x.map(y=>y/2|0)),g(x.map(y=>++y/2|0))].sort((x,y)=>x-y))
// 85
a=>a.map(x=>[(g=h=>new Set(x.map(h)).size)(y=>y/2|0),g(y=>++y/2|0)].sort((x,y)=>x-y))
// 80
a=>a.map(x=>[(g=n=>new Set(x.map(y=>(y+n)/2|0)).size)(0),g(1)].sort((x,y)=>x-y))
// 79
a=>a.map(x=>[(g=n=>new Set(x.map(y=>y/2+n|0)).size)(0),g(.5)].sort((x,y)=>x-y))
// 76
a=>a.map(x=>[0,.5].map(n=>new Set(x.map(y=>y/2+n|0)).size).sort((x,y)=>x-y))
```

Comment: Nowhere is it written that the output has to be sorted from min to max. The question only says that the input will be sorted.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire; while true that the consistent sorting of the output is not currently included in the spec, arminb has commented on a couple of solutions stating that it *is* indeed a requirement. I have already [commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154942/how-many-pages-have-i-torn-out/154999?noredirect=1#comment378195_154942) on the challenge asking for it to be included and stating my preference against it - after all, to me, that would fall under strict I/O.

Comment: I think [this should work](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoMgGIR3n8IR0r9EMCk6wAN0aAdHwkAsGhoLRkhr@/KWmg53yX03fHfzNLFf3JyOPtzsNojNCGnIw8xoFVJVQPU@nJDevsrOJrTuwGdwcFJSjEl0H5s7LAlhvPXBxzBZMoURnbvrhcS0OD@64Y1QYUohywEZXGCkFIcGaJUlFQXGWE6tQTGooWmgaaH9XTVQzv/4BDwToDTvPcC0xln6BQ) for 64 bytes. However, your current sort method without any callback is flawed. It would fail on e.g. `[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,18]`.

Comment: Thanks, @Arnauld. Had just finished writing an update to map over `[0,.5]` instead of using `g` when I spotted your comment. Don't know why I have such a mental block with bitwise operators! I was hoping that the output sorting wouldn't become a requirement and that nobody would notice my broken `sort()` in the meantime ;) Need to get some work done so will be back in a while to update.

Comment: @Shaggy What is the original intent of `y/2`?  What is the reasoning of dividing the page number in half for this algorithm?

Comment: @MicFin, after dividing `y` by `2`, the result is bitwise ORed with 0 which rounds floats down so, essentially, `y/2|0` acts as a shortcut for `Math.floor(y/2)` but can, as Arnauld pointed out, be further shortened to `y>>1`. (e.g. `Math.floor(8/2)===Math.floor(9/2)===(8/2|0)===(9/2|0)===(8>>1)==(9>>1)===4`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 37 bytes

<sup>Thanks @MartinEnder for 8 bytes!</sup>

```
Sort[Length@*Split/@{#,#+1}~Floor~2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8T84v6gk2ic1L70kw0EruCAns0TfoVpZR1nbsLbOLSc/v6jOKFbtv6Y1V0BRZl6Jg1YaUJqLq9pQx6hWh6vaXMdCx9DAAIiBAkZGQGwMEjbSMdaxsNCxsNSxBMkZ6xiam9dycdX@BwA)

#### Explanation

In: `{3, 4, 5}`

```
{#,#+1}
```

Take (input) and (input + 1). `{{3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}`

```
... ~Floor~2
```

For each number from above, take the largest even number less it. `{{2, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 6}}`

```
Length@*Split/@
```

For each list from above, split the list by same elements `{{{2}, {4, 4}}, {{4, 4}, {6}}}`

and take the length of each: `{2, 2}`

```
Sort[ ... ]
```

Sort the output.

Comment: You don't need `SplitBy`: `Length@Split@⌊#/2⌋&/@{#,#+1}&` works. But then it's even shorter to do the flooring before the map: `Length@*Split/@⌊{#,#+1}/2⌋&`. And if you like, you can get the same byte count without Unicode: `Length@*Split/@{#,#+1}~Floor~2&`

Comment: Uh, I think the challenge requires a strict I/O format.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 95 + 1 (`-a`) = 96 bytes

```perl
@0=@1=0;map{$i=-1;$F[$i]+1==$F[$i+1]&&$F[$i]%2==$_&&$i++while++$i<@F&&++@{$_}[0]}0,1;say"@0/@1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnBCoJAFEX3fsVDJjcv670RmxEbmJW7vkBEXAgNWEoGEeKvN03G5cI95079Y8i9t2QsGypv3bQIZ1IuRVUL1yAbsy3kJkn@bieDawM5xNfVDT2icGdbJQmiXUS71tSstOdy7t6xpaPl2HsFGpgolEFKGZpFEjLQGnQBxe/IgJXa5AlUYGCOQkB@xunpxvvs00t@ICafdl8)

Comment: There are some cases your program does not execute properly. I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required.

Comment: I don't see where any of your test cases are failing.  The only thing that isn't working is multiple cases, which you added long after I posted my solution.  In any case, I have updated the solution to handle multiple tests.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 60 bytes

```
\d+
$*
.+
$&,/$&,
,(?=.*/)
1,
((11)+,)1\1|1+,
1
%O`1+
1+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYkxCsMwFEN3nSMNdiycyIbYGUqPkAtkSKEdunQoHXt356egJ3jS5/l9ve@tbY@AbkC07jkaoLtd4zB6iHBO8oFem34KhHBZdwVYuti3VlipaTLElJKRkZhZK@vC5TwyVcp/nFnMKR0) Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the page numbers to unary.

```
.+
$&,/$&,
```

Duplicate the list, interposing a `/`.

```
,(?=.*/)
1,
```

Increment the page numbers in one copy of the list.

```
((11)+,)1\1|1+,
1
```

Count the number of pages, but consecutive even and odd numbers only counts as one page.

```
%O`1+
```

Sort the counts into order.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert the counts back to decimal.

Comment: Nice submission! I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required. It seems your program is the only one by now which passes all the test cases.

Comment: Can't `,(?=.*/)¶1,` be something like `,.*/¶1$&` instead?

Comment: @Ven No, that would only increment one number, but I need to increment all of them.

Comment: Ok, and using overlapping takes it back to same byte count, so fair nuff

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
p t=sort[length$nub[div(p+o)2|p<-t]|o<-[0,1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwFIXh3afI0EHxVpIUTArt5ugbXDJELDbYJJf26tR3ryk4nOX74Yx@eQ/TtG0hUp5Z3Dz7yz0sfCDB/VIIpyG9eKzS54HP8D3SOZ/0Sl3Nbs1djRKUc1v0IfU0h8RV9CQI0YAFJUuVCrTWZY0D1NCAtWBbaPfUgDLmz1cwRUDtdz8)

Comment: I don't think this is technically valid, as the question requires a full program (`Your goal is to write a program, which takes a sorted, comma-delimmited list of numbers as input `)

Comment: @Ourous that' right. Also I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 163 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;
n->{for(int i=n.length;i-->0;){Set s=new HashSet(),t=new HashSet();for(int p:n[i]){s.add(p/2);t.add(++p/2);}n[i]=new int[]{s.size(),t.size()};}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU@xboMwFNzzFW@ExriBSIWUEqnq0qVTuiEGF0ziFGyEH6lS5G@nhhC1UYcn37t7Z90d2Yl5quHyWHxuBlE3qkU4WpJ2KCp6Fy/@cWUncxRKjmLTfVQih7xiWsMbExL6BYBGhpZ9UVJ3NW@fhMQ0S7MtlMkgvW1fqtaxHIhE0orLPR5i4XnbVez2O46gE8m/4JXpg90cl@DtHl/tzaNMReb2mrKicJr7wI1xgsvltJhRnrxTAHunxTcfP5yBiY0ZYht4rjHnPilRQG3LODtshdynGbB2r92pG8DcBpBrhGQmAfqQRMRfrez4JAgCO2tDrmJA1iSKSLQhm/FiTfwwvFUfSGgF4vu/9F9IAjNhE09PSVme8wadMYV74XZnjbymqkPa2NxYSee5bdlZ04Lz5l1d2lwck8UszPAD)

### Explanations

```java
n->{                                   // Input-output of int[][]
 for(int i=n.length;i-->0;){           // Iterate on books
  Set s=new HashSet(),t=new HashSet(); // Create two hashsets
  for (int p:n[i]) {                   // Iterate over each page
   s.add(p/2);                         // Add the sheet-of-page of books [ even | odd ] to one set.
   t.add(++p/2);                       // Add the sheet-of-page of books [ odd | even ] to the other set.
  }
  n[i]=new int[] {                     // change the input to the number of sheets used.
   s.size(),
   t.size()
  };
 }
}
```

Note: since there is no requirement about it, the min and max numbers of pages aren't ordered.

Comment: Can you chain `size` with `add` in Java to maybe save a few bytes? e.g., `s.add(p/2).size`.

Comment: @Shaggy No. I could chain stuff with streams, but that would *add* a <s>few</s> lot of bytes, not *save* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes

```apl
{(≢⍵)≤2:⌽≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2⋄≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUedix71btV81LnEyOpRz14Qt2PGo45Vh1Y86ukCymgYaoPkD283etTdgke2FmjgoRUa5goWCoYGBkBsqGBkZATExpoaRgrGChYWChaWCpYgGWMFQ3NziKiZgjlQQMHQUFMDhBSMNAE)

This can be done for less than half the byte count if the output order of pages doesn't matter:

```apl
{≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2}
```

#### How?

```apl
{(≢⍵)≤2:⌽≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2⋄≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2}⍝ Prefix dfn
{(≢⍵)≤2:                               ⍝ If argument length ≤2 
                    ÷2                 ⍝ Divide by 2
              ⍵(1+⍵)                   ⍝ Both the argument and 1+argument
             ⌊                         ⍝ Round down to the nearest integer
           ∪¨                          ⍝ Get the unique values of each
          ∘                            ⍝ And then
         ≢                             ⍝ Get the tally of elements of each
        ⌽                              ⍝ And reverse the result
                      ⋄                ⍝ Else
                       ≢∘∪¨⌊⍵(1+⍵)÷2} ⍝ Same as above, without reverting the result.
```

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqkuhHvd0lQNajzkWPOmY86lh1aMWjnq5HvVs1DLWBpObh7UaxtUDFh1ZomCtYKBgaGACxoYKRkREQG2tqGCkYK1hYKFhYKliCZIwVDM3NIaJmCuZAAQVDQ00NEFIw0uR61DvXRMFUAYjMFMAqFAyBEIiMFAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>222</s> <s>210</s> <s>204</s> 196 bytes

```
import StdEnv,ArgEnv,Data.Maybe,qualified GenLib as G
Start=tl[let(Just l)='G'.parseString i;?s=sum[1\\n<-[s,s+2..last(sort l)]|isAnyMember[n,n+1]l]in zip2(sort[?0,?1])['/\n']\\i<-:getCommandLine]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDRSsMwFIbvfYrcdWOndenAdroxhpOhbCDsMs3F6ZqVQJLOJBUmPrsxqwpe/Jx8/wkc@I5KoAm6a3oliEZpgtTnznpy8M2TeYe1ba9jgx6zPV5qAW89KnmSoiFbYXayJujI9ubg0fqlV0wJP3rpnSdqvEy2SXZG68TBW2laIh9Wbul6zWhVmUXKHLhJnmUKnR@561E15p/Src1lL3QtLDNgJpQrLg35kOd8@MRWU1hRPmbJbWUSXlVykd63wj92WqNpdtIIHkJgBZRAp9MYCnmex8x4YDnMoCyhnMP8upoBLYrf@g6K2AClkYdAzr@OJ4WtC2kd0uZiUMtjhOdd2PyHH0nDMzoR9q9/VehPndUDRKHR1jc)

Full-program requirements absolutely murder Clean's ability to compete.

For those who have been paying attention to my answers in Clean, you'll notice `import qualified`, which is an ugly hack to get around using modules that shouldn't be used together, together - which is only needed here because of another ugly hack to do with `GenLib` depending on `Data.Maybe` instead of `StdMaybe`, which is the result of *yet another* ugly hack in the libraries translated from Haskell's `Data` to get functionality before Clean's own libraries are equally complete.

Takes input via command-line arguments.

Comment: Nice submission. I updated the challenge with 2 extra input/output lines. Also strict I/O is not required.

Comment: @arminb Thanks! I'll be able to shorten it a lot tomorrow in that case.

Comment: @arminb I've updated it so it should be valid with the new cases. If the I/O I've used isn't acceptable, I'll revise it again in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
½₍⌈⌊vUvLs
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCveKCjeKMiOKMinZVdkxzIiwiIiwiNyw4LDEwMCwxMDEsMjIyLDIyMyJd)

Append a `\/j` for strict I/O compliance (12 bytes)

```
½         # Halve each
 ₍⌈⌊      # Floor and ceiling of each, paired
    vUvL  # Count unique items in each
        s # Sort
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 40 bytes

Inludes `+1` for `a`

```
perl -aE 'say/$/*grep${$.}{$_*$`|1}^=1,@F for-1,1' <<< "7 8 100 101 222 223"
```

Output is not ordered.

Assumes positive page numbers (especially no page `0`). Assumes missing pages are only mentioned once. Doesn't care if the input is ordered or not.

Processing only one book per run saves `3` bytes for `37`:

```
perl -aE 'say/$/*grep$z{$_*$`|1}^=1,@F for-1,1' <<< "7 8 100 101 222 223"
```